# Should I Use the jQuery-UI-Map Plugin?

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps

I'm thinking about using [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/), which is a google map plugin. Are there any disadvantages to using this plugin? Will I have access to all of the methods, events, etc. that are in the regular Google Maps API? Any reasons not to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the methods are accessible, however not through the plugin, e.g. the distance matrix is not a method in the plugin. All events in the Google API can be bound to any Google Maps object with the plugin.

Performance wise it will always be better to use the API instead of a plugin. If you are using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ then the overhead would be ~4kb and between 0 - 50 milliseconds if you compare adding 10000 markers with the plugin and 10000 markers with 
Google API. 4kB extra is not that much especially when compared to jQuery ~31KB, jQM ~20KB + ~7KB CSS, Google Maps js files (~85KB) (plus atleast ~80KB in images).